# XML XSLT incrementing a variable by 1

Tags: xml, xslt

I've checked some answers to similar questions but none fully fit the bill.

I've got a *XML* form that pulls a unique `Case ID` number generated by a service desk program using an *SQL* server. The `Case ID` is a twelve digit number that does increment by `+1` on every new call created.

But, for reasons too lengthy to go into, I need to display, for example, new call `123456789101` as `123456789102`. But only submit the original `Case ID` to the database.

I don't know anything about *XSL* template scripting but think I have to pass through `CaseID` as a Variable i.e. v`arNewCaseID` with a `+1` but I don't have a clue how to start.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If this is about XSL transformation, please show an example of the input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unclear what you are asking for, but in general:

If you have the XML tag `CaseID` and want to increment it, simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//CaseID"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CaseID">
  <xsl:value-of select=". + 1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will output the value of all `CaseID` XML tags incremented by one.

Comment: @Andy That is great! Please accept the answer if it worked for you.